# DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories only accessible Folders and those that aren't hidden

Tags: c#, directory, filesystems

```
var directory = DirectoryStructure.GetDirectoryContents(absolutePath);
var directorySubdirectories = new List<DirectoryInfo>(directory.EnumerateDirectories());
```

I want the EnumerateDirectories Method only to return visible Folders.
Like the Windows File Explorer.

e.G. this Folders i don't want to get returned:

[image: These are folders that i don't want to see]

Which searchPattern or searchOption can i use and how to achieve this goal?

Comment: You could filter the list on DirectoryInfo.Attributes to remove those with FileAttributes.Hidden set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter out the directories after enumerating them;

```
        ...
        var directorySubdirectories = new List<DirectoryInfo>(directory.EnumerateDirectories());
        var notHiddenAndNotSystemSubdirectories = directorySubdirectories.Where(d =>
          !d.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)
          && !d.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System)).ToList();
```